# Shouldn't a breadth first search only take $O(m)$ time?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

We assume the following (fairly standard) implementation for BFS.

```
1  procedure BFS(G,start_v):
2      let Q be a queue
3      label start_v as discovered
4      Q.enqueue(start_v)
5      while Q is not empty
6          v = Q.dequeue()
7          if v is the goal:
8              return v
9          for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
10             if w is not labeled as discovered:
11                 label w as discovered
12                 w.parent = v
13                 Q.enqueue(w)
```

The standard claim for the time complexity for BFS is that it takes $O(m+n)$ time, where $m=|E|, n=|V|$. I'm going to argue that we can improve this bound to $O(m)$, at least when the graph is undirected (the result should also hold in the directed case, with small modifications to the argument below).

The reason I believe this to be the case is that a call to `BFS(G, s)` is *essentially the same thing* as a call to `BFS(G', s)` where $G'=(V', E')$ is the connected component of $G$ containing $s$. By "essentially the same thing", I mean that the execution of the algorithm in either case will be identical.

It follows that an upper bound for the running time of the algorithm is $O(|V'| + |E'|)$.  We have that $|E'| \leq m$. Since $G'$ is connected, we also have that $|V'| \leq |E'| + 1 \leq m+1$. It follows that the running time is also bounded by $O(m+1+m) =O(m)$.

Is there anything wrong with this reasoning? If so, explain why and exhibit an instance of the above algorithm wherein the running time is demonstrably worse than $O(m)$. If not, I have to ask why the running time is most commonly given as  $O(m+n)$?

Comment: No this is not correct. There is a good answer for this already on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549140/breadth-first-search-time-complexity-analysis

Comment: @MorganRodgers I don't think that post answers the question.  Every $O(m)$ is also $O(m+n),$ so an answer that shows it is $O(m+n)$ doesn't answer "Why isn't it $O(m)$?"

Comment: @BrianMoehring "What's actually happening here is that no matter how many edges there are in the graph, there's some baseline amount of work you have to do for each node independently of those edges." That actually seems pretty good. Every $O(m)$ is *not* also $O(m+n)$. Only one of those increases in complexity when $n$ grows and $m$ does not.

Comment: @MorganRodgers That sentence doesn't seem correct. If you have a graph with say a million nodes, but the graph only has a single edge, (say an edge from the source node $s$ to some node $v$), then the BFS will still run pretty quick: you won't need to process the $10^6 - 1$ nodes disconnected from $s$, at least with implementations similar to the one in the question.

Comment: @MorganRodgers That is a good argument for "Not every $O(x+y)$ is $O(x)$" and "Not every $O(x)$ is $\Theta(x+y)$" but neither relates to what I said.  I said "Every $O(m)$ is also $O(m+n)$."  This is simply due to $m,n \geq 0$ and $f(m,n) \leq C\cdot m \leq C\cdot (m+n)$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 From a particular source node. But to search the graph, you will have to search from each source node, correct? Otherwise you need an algorithm to decide the proper source node to start from.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I misinterpreted what you were saying. MathematicsStudent1122 seems to be trying to show that this $O(m+n)$ is in fact $O(m)$; I do feel like those linked answer address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the standard claim is that running BFS to discover the whole graph is $O(n+m)$. Your procedure just discovers the component of your start vertex, and does indeed do that in $O(m)$ time (modulo some concern about exactly how it is represented, since you need to be able to look up the neighbours of any given vertex in time that doesn't depend on how many vertices there are). To make it explore the full graph, though, you'd need to check after each iteration whether there are any vertices you haven't seen, and if so do another iteration from a suitable start vertex.